# What does "blowing across" mean?

Tags: phrasal-verbs

There is the sentence:

> There's fog blowing across the montain peak.

What does "blowing across" in this situation mean? Is it connected with blowing of the wind?

Comment: 2.(intransitive) If something blows, the air moves it. - https://simple.wiktionary.org/wiki/blow

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When the wind blows, it means that it moves.  When something blows, it means that it is moved by the wind.

The sentence "There's fog blowing across the mountain peak" means that there's  fog moving with the wind from one side to the other side of the mountain peak.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it means that the wind is lightly carrying the fog across the mountain peak.

Comment: I don't think it implies 'lightly', just movement